# Android app websocket request very slow

Tags: c#, android, node.js, xamarin, websocket

I try to test websocket through an Android application with Xamarin and a nodeJs server. I have a speed problem with the socket.emit request : it is very slow (about 20 seconds, it's the delay between the button click and the moment when I see "console.log(data)" on the nodejs console). However it is quick with the socket.on to receive data. I don't know why.
My code is very basic I know but it is only to see how the websocket works.

Android app

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;

namespace TestWebSocket
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestWebSocket", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private Socket socket;
        private EditText textEnvoi;
        private EditText textReponse;
        private Button button;
        private string dataSend;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {   
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);           

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            textEnvoi = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.sendText);
            textReponse = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.reponseText);            

            button.Click += delegate {
                socket = IO.Socket("http://192.168.1.xx:8080/");
                dataSend = textEnvoi.Text;

                socket.Emit("txt", dataSend);

                socket.On("dataReceive", data =>
                    {
                        //textReponse.Text = data.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("Texte : {0}", data.ToString());
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    }
}
```

NodeJs code

```
var http = require('http');

// Chargement du fichier index.html affiché au client
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end("content");
});

// Chargement de socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Quand un client se connecte, on le note dans la console
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('txt', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
       socket.broadcast.emit("dataReceive", data)
   })


});

server.listen(8080);
```